# Profiling browser performance of application in production

Tags: javascript, performance

I am wondering how to profile the browser performance of application in production. I am using Chrome with the minified version of our javascript code deployed to production.

I am looking to analyze some CPU profiles and heap snapshots but the data is all cryptic given the minified JS. Any suggestions on how people approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using source maps?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/